# Excel sheet doubts in vbscripting

Tags: vbscript, excel.application

I am creating an excel file as shown below
             strFileName = "c:\test.xls"

```
         Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         objExcel.Visible = True

         Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
         objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)

         objExcel.Quit
```

Now after some data manipulation i populate some values into the excel sheet manually in sheet1 and sheet2 of the same excel sheet.
I would be glad if anyone could tel me how to compare two values in two different sheets of the same excelk sheet
For eg:
sheet1 has

```
             **Executables**             **checkbox**
                E1                             yes
                E2                             No
                E3                             yes
```

and sheet2 has
                  Executables        Number of parameters   input1  Input 2
                     E1
                     Send               2                      4     {ENTER}
                     Put                2                    Input.xls   {ENTER}
                     Send               2                       4        {ENTER}                                                            {ENTER}
                    
    Now i want my vbscript shud search in sheet 1 for each yes and then come here and search in sheet2.How would i do a  comparitive search on sheet1 and sheet2 in the same excel sheet files

```
        Thanks
        Maddy
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using two sheet objects to compare the values
This will compare each cell in sheet1 to the same cell in sheet2.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xls")
Set objSheet1 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set objSheet2 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

For i = 1 To objSheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For j = 1 To objSheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        if (objSheet1.Cells(j, i).Value = objSheet2.Cells(j,i).Value) Then
            'Equal do something
        else
            'Not Equal do something
        End IF
    Next
Next

objExcel.Quit
Set objSheet2 = Nothing
Set objSheet1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your data need to be stored in form elements, or can you just use the spreadsheet functions?  A simple VLookup formula will compare two sheets, but can only search data contained in cells.

```
     SHEET 1
  Boy     Age
1 Joe     13
2 Jimmy   12
3 Jack    27
```

In the 2nd sheet, use the following formula:

```
 =if(vlookup(a1,'[Sheet 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$2,2,false)=a2, "Same", "Different")

     SHEET 2
  Boy     Age   Formula
1 Joe     14    Different
2 Jimmy   12    Same
3 Jack    27.5  Different
```

Comment: just shud compare the values between two sheets.How would i switch the control between two sheets of the same excel sheet.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include examples...  To make writing the formula easier, you can simply type =vlookup( then click the cell containing the "known match" between the two sheets.  Then hit a comma on the keyboard, navigate to the place you want to perform the lookup, and highlight it.  Hit comma, type 2, type false, close parens...  You're good to go.